# UrlEncoder encoded string not working?

Tags: android, url, encoding

Hello i have to pass json in get method url for that I have used retrofit library.

http://jbossdev-*****.*****.com/****/web/rest/waitlistRestAction/checkinusers?orgid=2&pagerReqParam={"filters":null,"sort":null,"sortOrder":null,"pageSize":500,"pageNo":1}

I want to encode json which is
{"filters":null,"sort":null,"sortOrder":null,"pageSize":500,"pageNo":1}

**Correct encoding :**

http://jbossdev-*****.*****.com/kyobee/web/rest/waitlistRestAction/checkinusers?orgid=2&pagerReqParam=%7B%22filters%22:null,%22sort%22:null,%22sortOrder%22:null,%22pageSize%22:500,%22pageNo%22:1%7D

**What i got after pass encoded string in url**

http://jbossdev-*****.*****.com/*****/web/rest/waitlistRestAction/checkinusers?orgid=2&pagerReqParam=%257B%2522filters%2522%253Anull%252C%2522sort%2522%253Anull%252C%2522sortOrder%2522%253Anull%252C%2522pageSize%2522%253A500%252C%2522pageNo%2522%253A1%257D

```
  @GET(General.CHECK_IN_USERS)
    Call<CheckInUsers> checkInUsers (@Query(ORG_ID) String orgId , @Query(PAGER_REQ_PARAM) String pagerReqParam);


 String query = URLEncoder.encode (reqParam, "WINDOWS-1252");           
            mAPIService = General.getClient ().create (APIService.class);
            Call<CheckInUsers> checkInUsersCall = mAPIService.checkInUsers (orgId, query);
            checkInUsersCall.enqueue (new Callback<CheckInUsers> (){
                @Override
                public void onResponse (Call<CheckInUsers> call, Response<CheckInUsers> response){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented Interface similar to this , try with `encoded = true` for required parameters

Example:

```
public interface APIInterface {

    @GET ("loginapi.php")
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    Call<LoginPOJO> loginResponse(
                                    @Query(value = "password",encoded = true) String password,
                                    @Query(value = "key",encoded = true) String key,
                                    @Query(value = "uid",encoded = true) String uid,
                                    @Query(value = "email", encoded = true) String email
                                 );
}
```